# Hint the possibility to post image links instead of the actual image for low-rep users

Tags: feature-request, new-users, images, error-message, wording

I have recently come across a few question where an image would have been helpful to understand the question better - the user unfortunately did not have enough reputation to post images though and gets a message like this:

[image]

One of the most recent questions would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400751/xcode-6-ios8-auto-layout-how-to-set-constraint-priorities-right). He even wrote that he tried posting an image but was not allowed to. (By now he is able to because of the question upvotes)

I do understand that there are [good reasons not to allow everyone to post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268469/why-cant-users-with-less-than-10-reputation-points-add-images-while-asking-ques).

- I would however like to improve the shown "error message" to include a hint that you can still post the link to the image and probably a moderator will come and edit the question.

Something like

> You need at least 10 reputation to post images. You can still post the images as raw link - it will be included in the question after a moderator reviews it and considers it useful.

Is something like that already in development or has already been declined before?

Comment: I like this change - it's not entirely clear when you attempt to upload an image that posting a URL would be acceptable. It's perfectly possible that a URL to an image would be rejected as well, either automatically or because it's against a no-image-upload rule.